# how to disable haproxy after backend servers are down

Tags: haproxy

Can you any help me with this issue. I have installed haproxy loadbalancer. it is working perfect, but the problem is other. When the application connect to the backend server direct without loadbalancer and the server is down, the application say "trying to reconnect" - this is good, because a user know that the server is down. But wenn application is connect to loadbalancer and server is down, the application staying open and don't say "trying to reconnect". This is because the app is connect direct to haproxy and the app think, that everything is ok with connection. Do you have any ideas how to make haproxy to be disable or service to be shutdown when all backend servers are down and of course when some of the servers are up, haproxy to be up also

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking the same question as [How can I make HAProxy reject TCP connections when all backend servers are down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950483/how-can-i-make-haproxy-reject-tcp-connections-when-all-backend-servers-are-down/17712250#17712250)

You want to explicitly reject the connection if backend servers are down:

```
acl site_dead nbsrv lt 1
tcp-request reject if site_dead
```

Or `acl site_dead nbsrv(backend_name) lt 1` where `backend_name` is the name of a different backend.

[nbsrv documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/MatchingLayer4andBelow)

[acl documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/UsingACLs)

[tcp-reject documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/tcp_request_content_reject)