# How can I make HAProxy reject TCP connections when all backend servers are down

Tags: haproxy

We are using HAProxy to forward incoming TCP connections to a separate server that uses a raw TCP. The issue that we are seeing is that the client connection is accepted and then closed rather then rejected immediately. Since we have enabled a health check is there any way for HAProxy to unbind from the port so that the initial connection fails?

```
listen custom_forward
   mode tcp
   bind *:11144
   default-server inter 10m fastinter 20s downinter 1m maxconn 100
   server custom_server hostname:10144 check
```

Answer (score 14):

You want to explicitly reject the connection if backend servers are down:

```
acl site_dead nbsrv lt 1
tcp-request connection reject if site_dead
```

Or `acl site_dead nbsrv(backend_name) lt 1` where `backend_name` is the name of a different backend.

[nbsrv documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/MatchingLayer4andBelow)

[acl documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/UsingACLs)

[tcp-reject documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/tcp_request_content_reject)

Comment: you should add `connection` so it should be `tcp-request connection reject if site_dead` , otherwise haproxy fails at parsing config.

Comment: Sufficient for me, possibly more efficient: `tcp-request connection reject if { nbsrv(backend_name) lt 1 }`